# Duplicate documents in insertMany()

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb

## Duplicate documents in insertMany()

**Hi. I have quite a problem with the insertMany() function.**
My goal is:

- to observe a file named "List.json"
- if there are changes in it then reading the file
- then write documents from the file List.json to the database mongoDb
  List.json file is uploaded by user on the page.

The problem is that my function is working but it's writing me documents after 2 or 3 times. I don't know what it is caused by.
I would like one document from the List.json file to be added only 1 time.
If it is possible I would like the program to check if a document with the given "Nazwisko" already exists in the database. If it exists then do not add it to the database.

I do not use Moongose.
I use only mongoDb and node.js
I know little about mongo

**This is my function**

```js
fs.watch(file("Lista.json"), function (eventType, filename) {
  fs.readFile(file(filename), function (err, data) {

    const bazaJson = data; //fs.readFileSync(file("Lista.json").toString());
    const bazaJson1 = bazaJson.toString();
    const bazaJsonObject = JSON.parse(bazaJson1);

    client.connect((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("błąd polaczenia /manySaveDatabase");
        client.close();
      } else {
        const db = client.db("test"); //pobieram nazwe bazy danych test
        const candidate = db.collection("candidate"); // nazwa naszej kolekcji
        console.log("polaczenie udane z bazą /manySaveDatabase");

        try {
          candidate.insertMany(bazaJsonObject, {
            ordered: false,
          });
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("wystąpil blad e: ", e);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**This is my List.json file content**

```json
[
  {
    "Imie": "Katarzyna",
    "Nazwisko": "Mongoł",
    "Miejscowosc": "Kraków (Kraków-Śródmieście)",
    "Angielski": "Angielski C2"
  },
  {
    "Imie": "Marieta",
    "Nazwisko": "Mongołacc",
    "Miejscowosc": "Rybnik",
    "Angielski": "Angielski C1",
  },
  {
    "Imie": "Marieta",
    "Nazwisko": "Mcc",
    "Miejscowosc": "Rybnik",
    "Angielski": "Angielski C1"
  }
]
```

**This image shows one document being added 2 times, during one change to the List.json file.**
[image]

I have already looked through similar topics related to duplication on the stackoverflow forum. However, none of them solve my problem.
In my case, each document is uploaded more than 1 time. Uploading 100 such documents will add 200 records to the database.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code snippet you posted it seems that everything is fine, what I think is happening is that you're using `watch` to track file changes ( i'm assuming a different process writes data into that file or something of the sort) and it just triggers multiple times.

The `insertMany` is working as intended, you're just inserting the same document multiple times due to multiple file changes.

What I would do is build a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on the relevant fields that define a document uniqueness, potentially all fields.

Now when you try to insert a document that violates the uniqueness constraint it will fail, It is important to note that if you choose this solution you must use the `ordered: false` option for the `insertMany`. If you choose to remove it for whatever reason then a failed insert will make the any document that has not been inserted yet to fail as well.

> Inserting a duplicate value for any key that is part of a unique index, ... With ordered to false, the insert operation would continue with any remaining documents.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you very much @Tom Slabbaert**

Ultimately, I applied this solution:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "Mongoł",
    "Imie": "Katarzyna",
    "Nazwisko": "Mongoł",
    "Miejscowosc": "Kraków (Kraków-Śródmieście)",
    "Angielski": "Angielski C2"
  },
  {
    "_id": "Mongołacc",
    "Imie": "Marieta",
    "Nazwisko": "Mongołacc",
    "Miejscowosc": "Rybnik",
    "Angielski": "Angielski C1",
  },
  {
    "_id": "Mcc",
    "Imie": "Marieta",
    "Nazwisko": "Mcc",
    "Miejscowosc": "Rybnik",
    "Angielski": "Angielski C1"
  }
]
```

```js
fs.watch(file("Lista.json"), function (eventType, filename) {
  const bazaJson = fs.readFileSync(file("Lista.json").toString());
  const bazaJson1 = JSON.stringify(bazaJson.toString());
  const bazaJsonObject = JSON.parse(bazaJson1);
 
  var array = [];
  for (var key in bazaJsonObject) {
    array.push(JSON.parse(bazaJsonObject));
  }

  client.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
      client.close();
    } 
    else {
      const db = client.db("test"); 
      const kandydaci = db.collection("kandydaci");

      try {
        if (array.length != 0) {
          kandydaci.insertMany(array[0], { ordered: false });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        
        e.getWriteErrors().forEach(function (err) {
          if (err.code != 11000) {
            throw e;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I also found this article helpful:
http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/MongoDB.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there was another error related to `_id`
When I set `_id : "Surname"`, the file upload was successful. But apart from uploading files, my application allows to edit added documents.
Editing documents is done based on the unique `_id` generated by mongoDB.
All documents which have `_id` given by mongo can be edited. The ones that I have assigned myself are not editable.
I have tried downloading users by email, but they sometimes repeat themselves, because in the database I sometimes have the same person with different data.
Someone may have some advice?